# regex - scraping javascript

Tags: php, regex, dom, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape some data out of an HTML page that I'm getting with cURL. I've been using a PHP DOM lib called ganon; but in this case, the number I need is in Javascript.

```
{
  label: "Views<span class='Footnote'>*</span>",
  type: "other",
  id: "Views",
  value: "7"
}
```

I only need the `7`. So if I could match on `id: "Views",` and get everything up to the closing `}` and only return numbers; I believe this is possible -- I've been working on it but REGEX is certainly not my strong suite.

Comment: Don't use regex.  This block is a JSON string, try using `json_decode`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: That is no valid json, that is javascript.

Comment: @hakre: Ah, you're right, the keys aren't quoted.  Darn.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is rather straight forward:

```
$value = preg_replace('(.*value: "(\d+)".*)s', '\1', $scrape);
```

Gives you a string of `7`.

You can still prefix with the `id: "Views",` part, I leave that as an excercise.

Comment: Thank you! I see this works with the string above but I'm struggling to extract that code block from the HTML document. This is the actual file https://www.dropbox.com/s/22f5l34kp0d7qs9/blip.html (line 665)

Comment: Well, it was not meant to parse the full HTML. Let that work do by a HTML parser, one exists in PHP: [`DomDocument`](http://php.net/DomDocument). Fetch the javascript from within the one script tag it is in only. That greatly reduces your problems and the HTML parsing is stable. If you do scraping it's worth to know about it anyway.

Comment: I was able to parse the HTML down the the script node https://www.dropbox.com/s/22f5l34kp0d7qs9/blip.html. Still struggling to extract the value I'm after at line 128 now.